# Function that grows faster then BB(n) using quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-computation

Is it possible to define a function in terms of quantum computers that grows faster then any that is defined in terms of turing machines?

Answer (score 2):

No, [a quantum computer can be simulated by a classical one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29307/simulate-a-quantum-computer-on-a-normal-one), and hence anything that can be computed by a quantum computer can also be computed by a Turing machine.

The classical computer might take much longer than the quantum one, but the final result of the computation would be the same.